# .net 5: System.CommandLine: Exception when argument list is specified whose name begins with option name

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.commandline

Example code:

```cs
using System;
using System.CommandLine;
using System.CommandLine.Invocation;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rootCommand = new RootCommand
        {
            new Option<string>(alias: "--abc" ),
            new Argument<List<string>>(name: "abcd"),
        };
        rootCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create<string, List<string>>(command);
        return rootCommand.Invoke(args);
    }

    static void command(string abc, List<string> abcd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("option = \"{0}\"", abc);
        foreach (string argument in abcd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("argument = \"{0}\"", argument);
        }
    }
}
```

The argument name `abcd` contains the option name `abc` at the beginning. When run with no option but an argument: `dotnet run -- foo` an exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This does not happen, when the option is used to (e.g. `dotnet run -- --abc foo bar`).
Is this a bug or expected behavior because of wrong usage?

Edit after hint from @Caius Jard:

Testing references `abc` and `abcd` for null value does not help:

```cs
using System;
using System.CommandLine;
using System.CommandLine.Invocation;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rootCommand = new RootCommand
            {
                new Option<string>(alias: "--abc" ),
                new Argument<List<string>>(name: "abcd"),
            };
        rootCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create<string, List<string>>(command);
        return rootCommand.Invoke(args);
    }

    static void command(string abc, List<string> abcd)
    {
        if (abc != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("option = \"{0}\"", abc);
        }
        if (abcd != null)
        {
            foreach (string argument in abcd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("argument = \"{0}\"", argument);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn on "break when thrown" so you catch the error as soon as it happens (Debug menu, Exceptions, tick next to CLR). Maybe abcd is null

Comment: @CaiusJard Testing `abcd` for null value does not help. I'm working with vscode, does "break when thrown" work there too?